# Assign a calculated column a value

Tags: workflow, calculated-column

Is it possible to assign a value to a calculated column in a workflow, even if the formula for the column has already been set?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean manually set the value of the field directly to something other than what the formula spits out, then no you cannot do that.

If you need to do that type of thing what you can do is something like having a calculated field and a text field, and use the first to set the second. I would need to know more about your situation to give you a more specific answer.